# question related to mongoose find and update query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

using below query to find and return the posts

```
const posts = await Post.find(
                             {postedBy: new Types.ObjectId(user)}, 
                             "-bid -createdAt -updatedAt -__v", 
                             {new: true}).sort({ _id: -1 }
);
```

using below query to filter the above output and update only the selected document. this query not working at all.

```
const data = posts.filter((item:any) => item.expiredAt.getTime() <= currentDate.getTime())
        .map((val:any) => {
            Post.findOneAndUpdate({postedBy: val.postedBy},{ $set: {status: "expired"}});
        })
```

finally need to return the document that's why used two queries because update query won't return the document.

how can I update the only the selected document without run the update query several times?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. if someone face a similar issue try to add promise for the result query.

```
const data = posts.filter((item:any) => item.expiredAt.getTime() <= currentDate.getTime())
                  .map(({postedBy}) => (
                      Post.updateOne({postedBy},{ $set: {status: "expired"}})
                  ))
            Promise.all(data);
```